# Plot() only one column of data

Tags: r, quantmod

I use the following code in r to read a CSV file of stock prices.

```
library(quantmod)

#column headings ("open","high","low","close","volume","adj.")

fmt <- '%Y-%m-%d'
SPY <- read.zoo("~/Stocks/csv/SPY.csv",header=TRUE,sep=',',tz='',format=fmt,index=0:1)

plot(SPY['open'])
```

I can successfully use `plot(SPY)` to plot all columns.

How would I select just one column by name, for example plot just the "open" column? I've tried a bunch of things such as `plot(SPY['open'])` but can't figure it out.

Could somebody help? Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try:
plot(SPY[,'open']

The square brackets method of selecting a subset requires two expressions: first, one describing the rows, and second, one describing the columns.  These two expressions are separated by a comma.  When you want to include all the rows, just leave a blank before the comma, and specify the name of the column you want.

Your code, with only one expression, treats 'open' as a row, not a column.  The result is probably a strip chart, a one-dimensional graph, instead of the plot you were expecting.

Comment: `zoo` objects are actually matrices with special rownames. So it's inlikely that `SPY['open']` would return anything useful. They are not dataframes so the "[" function would not return a column (or a row) without the comma.